# Why is my drip line spraying, not dripping?

Tags: drip-system, irrigation

We recently noticed a small geyser in our landscape and found that the connector had been broken from the 1/2" line to the 1/4" drip line. I replaced it with a similar 1/4" barbed connector. Now instead of water dripping it is coming out in a full force stream. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The water is spraying out of the drip head, or from you're new connector?

Comment: Is it coming out from around the connector?  Is the hole where the barbed connector fits into the 1/2" line too large?   That would be my guess having had this happen to me in the past.  If so, I'd remove the big hole segment and  mend it (or patch it properly) and make a new hole.

Comment: Please take a picture of this, we are able to help.  Might as well describe just exactly what you've installed, where, what your thinking was/is.  Is this system connected to a backflow device out by your water meter?? Are you able to turn this off and it stops?  What is your pressure?  Please diagram your system.  We will be able to help you save lots of money...

Comment: Is the dripper the adjustable type or fixed? If fixed, was the regulator in the barb? (that would be insane, but... yeah.)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you have replaced a dripper with a simple connector.  In my tree farm I use a lot of drippers on the pipe, then run a piece of spaghetti tube to where I want the water.  You may have lost the dripper part of this assembly.

Pictures would help.  Take one of what you put in, and one next door to what is working correctly.